# A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected in Python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to make a console chat app in python using socket library.

Whenever I send a message to the server, the server code crashes with the following message:

> OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Server code

```
import socket

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) # get the ip address of PC
PORT = 5050

ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

socket.bind(ADDRESS)

while True:
  socket.listen()

  conn, addr = socket.accept()
  print(f"Connected by {addr}")
  while True:
    data = conn.recv(64)
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
    socket.send(data)
```

Client code

```
import socket

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) # get the ip address of PC
PORT = 5050

ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

socket.connect(ADDRESS)
while True:
  msg = input("Enter your message")
  socket.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
  data = socket.recv(64)
  print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

What I am trying to achieve is whenever I send a message to the server, the client script should print the sent message. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\Chat app trial\server.py", line 19, in <module>
    socket.send(data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to send data to your own server socket. You instead want to send to the client that you accepted.

```
socket.send(data)
```

Should be:

```
conn.send(data)
```

If you think about it, if you had multiple clients, how would you send data to a specific client? By using the socket that `accept` gave you.

---

As a side note, you probably don't want to import the module as `socket`, and also call your variable `socket`. It's fine here, but if you were to make a more complicated project, you may accidentally refer to the object when you meant to refer to the module. I'd rename the `socket` object to `sock` or `server_socket` to avoid shadowing.